# Why do I get these link errors?

Tags: c++, qt

When I try running a `Qt` application with the following `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "ui_checkabder.h"
#include <QDialog>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
Ui::CheckAbder ui;
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
ui.setupUi(dialog);
dialog->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.3/mingw/lib/libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o):-1: In function `WinMain@16':

`c:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src/winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:131: error: undefined reference to qMain(int, char **)`

:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And, `abder.pro` looks like this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Apr 18 09:52:56 2011
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
FORMS += checkabder.ui
```

How can I solve those errors? Provided that I'm using `Qt Creator`.

Thanks.

Comment: Might you be including something which already defines a main? An outside library for example?

Comment: Could you paste your .pro file, too?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld. Sure. I have included it in the original post

Comment: @user588855 Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

main.cpp is not built. Add the following to your .pro file:

```
 SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I crossed paths with this problem myself just now.

I got it when i tried to make the console window for my application disappear.

http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-12/thread00170-0.html

Be sure that the linker links qtmain.lib to your program, that's what fixed this for me.

Old Stuff:

I'd guess that your library was compiled with some different settings regarding what char is.

If this were Visual Studio, I'd select the treat w_char as built in type to false.

edit:

What Naszta said made me think the following: try adding

```
int qMain(int argc, char * array [])
{
    return 0;
}
```

If this works, something else might be broken (IMO).

Comment: well the only thing that comes into mind is that you haven't linked with the proper libraries. You need to add QtGui and QtCore as modules to the project, i have no idea how to do that with the QtCreator. But for pro files, you need this QT += gui, it should be there by default.. so remove this QT -= gui.

Comment: If I remember correctly, qtmain_win.cpp file has an extern that you need to provide for it. For some reason your *main* isn't compatible with it. Sorry, I don't know more. AFAIK your main should be enough for it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
QT += core gui
```

in your .pro file?

Answer (score -1):

Try add the followings:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    return main( nCmdShow, &lpCmdLine ); 
}
#endif
```