# Compilation Error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I am trying to break my large project into sub directories and run it as a single executable. But when I am executing the code it is giving me the following error:

1. qtmain_win.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `qMain(int, char**)'
2. collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone please explain what is the reason behind these errors...

Thanks in advance!!!!

I have made a .pro file in which all the path to the subdirectories are included. Then each directory has its own .pro and .pri file with a directory which is common in all the directories. This directory is made as a lib. Then there is a main with main.pro and main.cpp. I am pasting all the three files here:         Project's pro file:

```
# build all components recursive

TEMPLATE = subdirs

######## normal build process ########
#
# Make sure your Main.pro is in the last line to ensure correct linking!
#
SUBDIRS =D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes/Start/Build/Start.pro \
     D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes/MainMenu/Build/MainMenu.pro \
     D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes/Solar/Build/Solar.pro \
     D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes/Main/Build/Main.pro\
```

CONFIG += ordered

Main.pro:

```
# ################ include pri file #################
!include("Main.pri"):error("Main.pri not found")


# ################ override some pri settings #################
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MultiFuncTester
CONFIG =-static
QT +=core\
gui\


# ################ own sources #################
INCLUDEPATH +=D:/MultiFuncTester/
SOURCES +=../Sources/Main.cpp
```

Project's pri file which is common in all directories made as a lib

```
######################
# common stuff for all components
######################

TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG += static \
         warn_on \
         qt \

QT += gui \
      core \


INCLUDEPATH +=D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes \
DEPENDPATH +=D:/MultiFuncTester/Modes \

CONFIG += debug_and_release
CONFIG += build_all



CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
CONFIG_SUFFIX = dbg
} else {
CONFIG_SUFFIX = rel
DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG \
          QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT \
         NDEBUG
CONFIG(gcov) {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += -fprofile-arcs
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O0
}
}

CONFIG(crosstgt) {
#To be able to build Target run qmake as follows:
qmake CONFIG+=crosstgt
CONFIG_SUFFIX = $${CONFIG_SUFFIX}_tgt
DEFINES += TARGET_BUILD
}

OBJECTS_DIR = obj_$${CONFIG_SUFFIX}
MOC_DIR = moc_$${CONFIG_SUFFIX}
DESTDIR = lib_$${CONFIG_SUFFIX}
```

Comment: can you paste your code from qtmain_win.cpp ?

Comment: This what I am worried about. There is no such file I have made....I dont know from where I am getting such problems.

Comment: can you confirm that you have an "int main(int,char**)" in your code and that your target type is "app"?

Comment: my guess is that the file that contains your int main isn't be compiled - can you check the compiler output to ensure that source code file containing it is actually being included in the compiler

Comment: Did any of the answers to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700701/why-do-i-get-these-link-errors

Comment: it would help if you paste your main.cpp file and your project's pro file here

Comment: Now instead of the errors regarding                                 qtmain_win.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `qMain(int, char**)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exitstatus, I am getting errors ehich states::-1: error: Circular sub-d--MultiFuncTester-Modes-Solar-Build-Solar-pro-make_default-ordered <- sub-d--MultiFuncTester-Modes-MainMenu-Build-MainMenu-pro-make_default-ordered dependency dropped.